# phpMyAdmin - auth_type 'config' not working

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-server

On a Windows 10 machine, I have a local VB with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I've installed phpMyAdmin package, which works well with default auth_type=cookie.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

However, when I try to edit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and change auth_type to 'config' (as well as using my root credentials),

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'rootroot';
```

I get this image:

[image]

Is there some limitation for Ubuntu version? Maybe someone knows. Do not really feel like debugging the source code.

Thanks in advance!

Update:
Credentials are correct, checked them with mysql -u root -p
Here's the entire print_r of $cfg.

```
Array ( [blowfish_secret] => l2WkFOENKtuMAyJ7IR3m2JsU [Servers] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [auth_type] => config [host] => localhost [extension] => mysqli [controluser] => root [controlpass] => rootroot [pmadb] => phpmyadmin [bookmarktable] => pma__bookmark [relation] => pma__relation [table_info] => pma__table_info [table_coords] => pma__table_coords [pdf_pages] => pma__pdf_pages [column_info] => pma__column_info [history] => pma__history [table_uiprefs] => pma__table_uiprefs [tracking] => pma__tracking [userconfig] => pma__userconfig [recent] => pma__recent [favorite] => pma__favorite [users] => pma__users [usergroups] => pma__usergroups [navigationhiding] => pma__navigationhiding [savedsearches] => pma__savedsearches [central_columns] => pma__central_columns [designer_settings] => pma__designer_settings [export_templates] => pma__export_templates ) ) )
```

Comment: There's no limitation for Ubuntu, as far as I know. The problem is most likely to be that the connection information is wrong in your config file, just like the message says. Post the details you changed to set up the connection in the config file (host, port, username, etc.; obviously you may wish to redact the password!) Also, try connecting with the details you think should work using `mysql` from the command line in Ubuntu to make sure they're right.

Comment: Checked, they are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`controluser` and `controlpass` are credentials for the (optional) [configuration storage](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#linked-tables) area. The actual database connection username and password configuration options are called `user` and `password`.

Comment: Where can I find and change them?

Comment: @Denis The same place you've put `controluser` and `controlpass`. Check [the documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_user).

Comment: adding them manually to the config file (they were absent before) solved the issue. cheers!